# how to read the contents of a String with XML content and save it as an XML

Tags: java, xml, string, csv

I am trying to read the contents of a String containing XML fields:-

```
String developer = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.priceover.com/pg_2.73.xsd">
<version>2.73</version>
<api_request_id>hashkeyint</api_request_id> <priceover_url>http://www.priceover.com/</priceover_url>
<priceover_url_text>Online Deals at Priceover.com</priceover_url_text><partner_url/><market>US</market></document>";
```

Comment: Post the code you are using to parse the String and the error message/unacceptable output you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [Java's DOM library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/when.html).  Another is [Java's SAX library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I broke your question a little with the formation, however if your problems are only the qoutes you just need to mask them with a backslash that will look like that:

```
String example = "My string with \"quotes\"";
```

If your problem is primary about parsing the xml please read [eebbesen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17767203/995926).

Comment: I have posted the question again with the modified String.

Comment: No problem so far I just wanted to help you. Anyway that string you posted is no valid java code.